# extending a tagged private type in the ada language

Tags: ada

I want to add a procedure to my instantiation of the Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists that will print out the list. I also would like to hide some of the functions and procedures. If there is a better way, I would be happy to read it, but for now, I am trying to wrap the instantiation inside another package, and that means creating a new List and Cursor. The generic define them like this:

```
   type List is tagged private;
   pragma Preelaborable_Initialization(List);
   type Cursor is private;
   pragma Preelaborable_Initialization(Cursor);
```

I've tried

```
  package Collection is new Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists (New_Type);
   type Cursor is new Collection.Cursor;
   type List is new tagged Collection.List with private;
```

This seems to be working for Cursor, but List is causing `subtype indication expected` error.

How can I subtype a tagged private like List?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you both use `new` and `tagged`:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists;

package Example is
   type New_Type is new Integer;
   package Collection is new Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists (New_Type);
   type Cursor is new Collection.Cursor;
   type List is new Collection.List with private;
private
   type List is new Collection.List with null record;
end Example;
```

Comment: Be aware that if you extend `Collection.List` with anything other than `null record` you will have to declare overridings of all the functions in `Collections.List` that return a `List`.

Comment: That solved it, thanks. And I bear that warning in mind.